# Показать пользователей, которые не делали ставки

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы :

**bets**

user_id
bet_id
bet_placed_date
bet_amount

**users**
user_id
created_date
country_name
phone_number

```
    SELECT u.user_id, b.bet_id FROM users AS u
    LEFT JOIN bets AS b
    ON u.user_id = b.user_id 
    WHERE u.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM bets)
```

Нужно написать запрос, который оставляет только тех пользователей, которые не поставили ни одной ставки

Comment: а в чем проблема то собственно в этом запросе?

Comment: @teran не работает

Comment: что как именно не работает? Что ожидаете, и что получаете?

Comment: получается ошибка. Скинула описание ниже и ссылку на сайт . где гоняю запрос

Comment: А не подскажете. нафига выводить `b.bet_id`? У выбираемых записей ставок нет, так что можно было обойтись простым `SELECT u.user_id, NULL AS bet_id`...

Comment: И с точки зрения производительности вместо WHERE NOT IN лучше использовать WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT u.user_id
 FROM users AS u
 LEFT JOIN bets as b ON (u.user_id = b.user_id)
 WHERE b.bet_id IS NULL
```

После левого джойна ставок к юзерам, у вас у непоставиших ставки `bet_id` всегда будет NULL, по нему и отфильтровать.

Для варианта с `user_id not IN (select distint user_id from bets)` джойн ставок по сути не имеет смысла, и работать он будет медленнее, чем вышеупомянутый джойн+фильтрация

Comment: Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE b.bet_id IS NULL' at line 2

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tQb4QD51YNHLPyr8bA7KpJ/0

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova После `WHERE` вместо честного пробела стоИт неразрывный. И после `ON u.user_id = b.user_id` тоже.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tQb4QD51YNHLPyr8bA7KpJ/1

Comment: *работать он будет медленнее, чем вышеупомянутый джойн+фильтрация* WHERE NOT EXISTS будет ещё быстрее при наличии индекса по `bets(user_id)` (и я бы проверял именно это поле, а не `bet_id`).

Comment: Спасибо большое  @teran

Comment: @Akina спасибо большое

Comment: @Akina да, тащить `bet_id` в выборку не стоит.